# Custom validation rule not validating empty input

Tags: laravel-5

I am validating two fields in my controller as follows:

```
 'landings_day'     => 'numeric|landings|min:0',
 'landings_night'   => 'numeric|landings|min:0',
```

Both of them can't be 0 or empty at the same time, neither can they be smaller than 0.

my *landings* validation rule is defined as follows in my `AppServiceProvider.php`:

```
Validator::extend('landings', function ($attribute, $value, $parameters, $validator) {

            $landings_night_value = array_get($validator->getData(), 'landings_night');
            $landings_day_value = array_get($validator->getData(), 'landings_day');

            if (empty($landings_day_value) && empty($landings_night_value)) {
                return false;
            }

        return true;
    });
```

The validator fails if both are 0, but as soon as they are both empty the validator passes. I have also used an empty string `(== "")` to check if it is empty as well, but still it passes the validation.

How would you check if it's an empty string that is being passed through?

Comment: required won't help, it should only fail if both are empty, one can be empty if the other one is larger than 0

Comment: So required_if (https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/validation#rule-required-if) or required_without

Comment: @Autista_z Okay, got it to work with the required_without rule, I read the docs earlier but didn't quite think it through, thanks.